# Launcher activity not found

Tags: java, android, view, android-view

So I am redoing my app so that there will be an animation on the start screen of the app. The only problem is it seems you cannot start an app with a view class. At least I'm not really sure if you can. Here is my code. With this code i get a launcher activity not found in the console?

```
public class SplashLaunch extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashlaunch);
        final Main d = new Main(this);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setContentView(d);
            }
        }, 5000);
    }

}
```

Here is the manifest file. I have a feeling that I'm going to need to change this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Tripps.thesimplegame"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashLaunch"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SPLASHLAUNCH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".YouFailed"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.YOUFAILED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Android requires an activity to start.  You can very easily have your custom view as the root view of your activity, but there is no such thing as starting an app from a view.

Comment: So the only way would be to make a sweet that goes to the main class?

Comment: the sweet would be the launcher?

Answer (score 0):

Likely somewhere in your launcher activity you have an onCreate method:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.foobar);
    }
}
```

Just change the setContentView to your custom view:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MyCustomView view = new MyCustomView(this);
        setContentView(view);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Activity that you want to start when the app first starts MUST have the following Intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Why does it have to be the main class?

Comment: It's not referring to a class, it's referring to an action: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MAIN